# uploading two files with JSF results in two times the same file

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I have a JSF page + Bean to upload a file and preview the result (it's for images). In the bean the upload method puts the data (`base64`) in a list and the JSF page loops through the list to display the images.

So far it works as expected for the first image. But when I upload a second image there are two things that might go wrong:

- the first image gets uploaded again instead
- Or, with a little change in the code the second image does not get uploaded at all until I reselect the file again and upload it.

**JSF page**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm" prependId="false">

    <!-- here I loop through the list to preview the images -->
    <c:forEach var="image" items="#{bean.imageList}">
        <h:graphicImage value="#{image}" />
    </c:forEach>

    <!-- that's the upload -->
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.uploadFile}" />
</h:form>
```

**bean**

```
private Part uploadedFile;                // the Part with the uploaded file
private ArrayList<String> imageList;      // the list of images (base64 encoded)

public void uploadFile() throws IOException{
    if(null != uploadedFile){
        String imageType = "data:" + uploadedFile.getContentType() + ";base64,";    // will be something like: "data:image/png;base64,"
        InputStream inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();  // getting the inputStream from the Part
        byte[] imageData;                  // array to but the image data
        try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)){          // converting the inputStream to a buffered one
            imageData = new byte[bis.available()];        // initializing the byte array with the right size
            bis.read(imageData);           // reading / writing the image data

            // HERE: if I comment out the next line, the second upload will upload the first image again.
            // but if I set the Part to null, the second upload will result in nothing (page reloads, no data uploaded) and I have to upload it again
            uploadedFile = null;
        }
        imageList.add(imageType + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageData));    // this adds the base64 image string to the list of images
    }
}
```

My bean is `@ViewScoped` (I need it to be that way for other things).

So my guess was that the `Part uploadedFile` just didn't get the new image data for the second file, but as I said, when setting it to `null` it just skips the second upload process.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following.

```
    byte[] imageData = new byte[uploadedFile.getSize()];
    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)) {
        bis.read(imageData);
        uploadedFile.delete();
    }
```

- Using `Part.getSize()`
- Not relying on `available()` which makes no guarantee that *all* is available
- Using `delete()` to clear the bean

*(Not tried it myself.)*

Comment: The `Part.getSize()` works well ( it returns a `long` so I had to explicitly cast it to `int` but I don't expect the files to be big enough to actually exceed the size). When I tried the `delete()` it does not seem to do anything for the first file and when uploading the second file it throws me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Maybe it's deleting the first tmp file but in the second run it tries to delete the same file again..?

Comment: It seems to concern scoping & reuse. As uncomplicated person I would have used a second bean, _request_ scoped, for the file upload. You might also consider a different upload, maybe with HTML 5 support for multiple files.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions! I feel like not seeing the woods for all the trees :) The `scope`  sounds reasonable and I just tried using a `requestScoped` bean for the upload ... still working on the injection though, but that seems like another story. Thanks again

Comment: This answer only fixes a bug which is not symptomatically described in the question. This bug would only result in potentially broken images (particularly those which are larger than the hardware buffer), but not in duplicate images. It's beyond me why this non-answer is upvoted twice, it's more suitable as a comment or as a note on side of a true answer.

Comment: @BalusC a bit much for a comment; but you are right, the error probably is the scope logic.